# running a function when another is clicked using jquery

Tags: jquery

When i run this `$btns.first().click();` in the first function it doesnt action it where as if i click it (as per second function it works perfectly.  The result is the slides all show when i click on a tab instead of just one. And then when i click one of the inner buttons the slides all disapear leaving just one.  Which is correct.

http://jsfiddle.net/p259x/

I know this is hard to understand so hopefully the link helps.

Comment: I sorted it, i added display none to the slides > div. 

Thanks all for looking!

Comment: Awesome. I was about to post that I have no idea what you're talking about. I did anyways :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define the `$tabs.click()` function, `$btns` doesn't actually exist, so it's probably trying to click an `undefined` reference. Just put the `$tabs.click()` function declaration below the instantiation of `$btns`.

Also, when you click on a `$tabs` it doesn't update the screen correctly. The `return` call in a function means that it leaves the function at that point. It will NOT continue through and run any other lines of code that exist after it. So, in your `$tabs.click()` declaration, you should move the last line (`$btns.first().click()`) above your `return false;` statement.

Finally, you might want to move the `$tabs.first().click()` and `$btns.first().click()` lines, as they rely on the events being declared, and might not give you the results you want if they exist before the event declaration.